# Is there a way to use iOS 11 simulator on OS X El Capitan?

Tags: ios, macos, simulator

I want to use iOS 11 simulator on my Mac. Now my Mac is running OS X El Capitan 10.11.6. But it seems that iOS 11 simulator is only shipped with Xcode 9, which requires macOS 10.12 or higher. However, I don't want to upgrade OS X El Capitan. So, is there any way to use iOS 11 simulator on OS X El Capitan?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install Xcode 9 without updating macOS, but I don't understand why you should do it.
BTW, you can change the minimum required version in the Xcode bundle's plist. To do that:

- control-click the Xcode app
- click Open Package Contents
- go inside the Contents folder (you'll see info.plist)
- Open it with the Xcode versione you have already installed (XCode 7 or similar), and there you can edit value of Minimum system version field to whatever Mac OS version you have currently installed.

If you’re still running El Capitan, Apple doesn’t care about you so it's time to upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, does it really work? Does it just bypass the check of Xcode, but not make it work?

Comment: By the way, I don't want to upgrade my OS X EI Capitan mainly because my MacBook Pro is old and slow, and upgrading may make it become slower. My MacBook Pro uses HDD, not SSD.

Comment: It is disappointing that Apple "give up" old operating system so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [App Store page](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) the answer is **No**.. 
The latest version of Xcode requires macOS Sierra 10.12 or higher

**>> But**, you actually can change the minimum required version in the Xcode bundle's plist. To do that simply control-click Xcode app, click `Open Package Contents`, then go inside `Contents folder`, there you'll see `info.plist`. Open it with Xcode you have already installed, and there you can edit value of `Minimum system version` field to whatever version you have currently installed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, does it really work? Does it just bypass the check of Xcode, but not make it work?